# MIME Multipart Parser

Tags: php, mime, multipart

The company I work for provides bulk-mailing functionality to our clients [double opt-in, not spam, I promise] and we get a figurative *ton* of reports back via Feedback Loops from AOL, Comcast, Yahoo, etc. These are generally from people that signed up, don't want it anymore, have been conditioned to *not* click 'Unsubscribe' links, [because "that's how the spammers get you"] and simply mark all the messages as spam.

Now, these FBL emails follow a specific format where the message is multipart, there are one or two text parts, and then the original message is attached, usually with all recipient information stripped out. This *attached* email is also multipart and contains the unsubscribe link, but the section in the attached email the link occurs in is quoted-printable encoded and the link is longer than what quoted-printable allows for in a line, so it get munged. Occasionally the section seems to get base64-encoded, I think it happens if the client is using a fancy language like chinese/japanese/etc.

What I need is a mime/multipart data parser that can give me these parts. PHP has *oh so helpfully* not implemented any form of multipart parser that I can find outside of what's internal to either their horrid IMAP functions, or internal to PHP itself which processes multipart form data.

Does anyone know of something I can use for this short of having to write my own? I had found [one script](http://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/source/browse/trunk/MimeMailParser.class.php), but it relies on old PECL functionality that relies on a custom-compilation of PHP which is not an option for this server.

**TL;DR:** PHP's imap_* functions will parse the parts of the message received from the server, but I need to parse the parts of an email *attached* to the email downloaded from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guy's script is ugly as sin, but it gets the job done:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3169-PHP-Decode-MIME-e-mail-messages.html